# Badges to improve quality of reviewing

Tags: discussion, review-audits, badges

Everyone, who did some reviewing should have noticed 'test' questions and answers (review audits) that are aimed for monitoring of review quality. I don't know what is supposed to happen when one continuously does not pass review audits, but I think we could reduce number of 'robo-reviewers' if we introduced badges like these:

> **Attentive** *bronze badge* passed 1 review audit
>
> **Concentrated** *silver badge* passed 10 review audits in a row
>
> **Focused** *gold badge* passed 25 review audits in a row

Well, I'm not sure of the names and quantities of review audits to pass, but the idea may be worth trying. What do you think?

Comment: There are allready badges for reviewing, audits are necessary for filtering out bad reviewers, so I would not see such badges as useful.

Comment: I'm not necessarily against this idea, but as long as there are incorrect audits in the system, I cannot give this my vote.

Comment: In other words, no driver would expect a medal for that he has repeatedly passed an alcohol control. :-)

Comment: Indeed, this is akin to grant badges to users that capitalize their "I"s properly or format their code correctly. Such behavior should go without saying, adding badges will only make people think proper formatting (or in our case, proper reviewing) is optional and not expected from the get-go.

Comment: Maybe remove the badges for reviewing, then there will be no robo-reviewers, as there will be no 'prize' ;). Or increase reputation level for reviewing, as I think users with higher reputation don't hunt for new badges so eagerly.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I see your point, but what happens to those who are repeatedly not passing the review audits? They are blocked in some way?

Comment: @Mark, yes, they are banned from reviewing, for increasing amounts of time (IIRC it starts at one week).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, OK, if there is punishment for them, we don't have to reward others ;-)

Comment: If we make "Concentrated" a requirement for earning the current review badges, I'm in. /wishful thinking